# Как правильно написать запрос с BETWEEN?

Tags: php, mysql

В БД есть 2 поля с датами. Поля `from` и `to` содержат даты "от" и "до", например "20150517" и "20150520".

Формой я отправляю две даты, и те пользователи кто входит в заданный промежуток показываются.

[Вопрос на Тостере](https://toster.ru/q/217480).

Comment: Есть какие-то причины чтобы вместо настоящего типа DATE использовать строки?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE DATE(from_date) >= '2015-05-01' AND DATE(to_date) <= '2015-05-23'
```

<sub>это ответ от [самого emtecif на тостере](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=585589). не уверен чем его не угодил `BETWEEN`, но судя по всему выборка нужна по раздельным колонкам и он тут просто не применим</sub>

Comment: BETWEEN работает с тремя аргументами, а тут их четыре.

Comment: @artoodetoo я знаю как работает beetween, но невозможно протелепатить точное значение "входит в заданный промежуток" на основе данных из вопроса.

Comment: это да, вопрос оставляет простор для фантазий.

Comment: @emtecif, вы точно проверяли это условие? Насколько я знаю, чтобы отследить пересечение, в этой формуле надо аргументы расставить **в другом порядке** — сравнивать меньшее из одного интервала с большим из другого.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос сформулирован неоднозначно, поиграю в телепата:
Два поля с датой в таблице и две даты в форме: предположу, что вы имели в виду пересечение двух периодов т.е. хотябы один совпадающий день в обоих периодах.
Ответ "в лоб":

```
… WHERE
  (:d1 BETWEEN `d_from` AND `d_to`) OR
  (:d2 BETWEEN `d_from` AND `d_to`)
```

Вариант, оптимизированный под использование индексов:

```
… WHERE
  (`d_to` >= :d1 ) AND (`d_from` <= :d2)
```

http://artoodetoo.ru/2015/03/intersect-periods/

Comment: Дорогой анонимный минусатор, было бы хорошим тоном указать причину или хотябы повод для минуса ))) Боитесь засветиться?